# How to reference Image Class in C# winforms?

Tags: c#

I'm making a new Project which is a class library.

[image]

my problem is I always got this error:

```
The type or namespace name 'Drawing' 
does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

this is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public void ReturnImage(object imageStream)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] data = (byte[])imageStream;
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
                return Image.FromStream(ms);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm planning to use this class to serve as a repository of common methods that I will be reusing in my program. In the above code, I have a public method `ReturnImage` which supposedly will accept an object and returns an `Image`.

But why I get that error? Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add reference to System.Drawing

From VS menu: Project > Add Reference

And to save you from incessant typing of: `using namespacehere;`

Press `Ctrl+.`  (<kbd>Control</kbd> and <kbd>.</kbd>), it will automatically insert `using namespacehere;` on top of your code based on the classes you use.  Example, place the cursor on any character inside `Image` of `Image.FromStream`, then press `Ctrl+.`, it will automatically insert `using System.Drawing;` on top of your code. Likewise, do the same(pressing `Ctrl+.`) on `FromStream` of `Image.FromStream`, it will automatically insert `using System.IO;` on top of your code